# Can't find Ubuntu drivers for the HP Envy 4520 printer

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, hp

My daughter bought me an HP Envy 4520 AllInOne printer.  I am trying to install drivers for that printer on Ubuntu and when I go to the HP Linux site, I see lots of printers but not that one.  Has anyone managed to install drivers that will work for that printer on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: So does the printer not work?

Comment: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/other/envy_4520_series.html Download and install from HP's site.

Comment: I downloaded "hplip-3.16.3.run" and I am not sure what to do with it.  Please forgive my ignorance....lots of windows experience, not a lot of linux experience.

Comment: The printer works from windows machines on the network but ubuntu does not even see it.  I can ping the IP fine, but I assumed I couldn't see the printer because I don't have a driver installed for it.

Comment: Ok, did some research and figure out what to do with a run file.  I ran it, it asked me a bunch of questions for which I didn't have an answer, took defaults where ever I could and guessed at the rest, and I worked.  thank you very much.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 and above has driverless printing

Comment: There is also the option to scan directly to a smartphone using the HP Smart App. It works wonders!

Answer (score 1):

Just bought a HP envy 4520 and it works out of the box with CUPS. No driver installation was needed.

I just connected it to my wifi and added the printer using auto discover. Scanning is also working without any further configuration or installation.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to configure Ubuntu 19.10 with HP envy 4520. I had no issues with 18.04, 18.10, and 19.04, as it used to auto-discover both the printer and the scanner over Wi-Fi with no human intervention. However, in 19.10 I had to do it manually.

To add the printer, in `Applications`, go to `Printers` and click `Add`. This should automatically find the printer and add it to the list. You can double check by printing a document. Adding a scanner is a little trickier.

To add the scanner, based on [HpAllInOne](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo), I had to run `sudo hp-setup`. If you get `error: hp-setup requires GUI support`, you need to run `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`. Retry `sudo hp-setup`, and it should open a GUI window<sup>1</sup>. From there, it wouldn't auto-detect the scanner over Wi-Fi, as it couldn't find any scanners. So, click `Back` and on the start page, click `Advanced`. Enter your printer's IP<sup>2</sup> and confirm. Now if you go back to `Printers` utility, you should see your scanner there.

---

<sup>1</sup>If that didn't work, refer to the link above. You may need to install `python3-pyqt4`.

<sup>2</sup>You can find the IP in at least two ways: (1) if your printer is already detected, go to `Printers`, click the gear icon, then `Printer Details`, and you'll see the `Address` there; (2) in your printer's interface, go to network settings and look for the IP address. It goes without saying, but you should be connected to the same Wi-Fi network!

Comment: My HP Envy on wifi seems to be discovered by my Ubuntu 20.04 but won't print.

Comment: This got my printer working on Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296010/ubuntu-20-04-hp-4520-printer-recognized-by-hp-setup-tool-but-tool-hangs-on-step#comment2333288_1296121

Answer (score 1):

After the latest update to ubuntu 20.04 dated 22/5-2020 the hp envy 4520 funktion as it should.

Previous when i added the printer to my system it added the printer twice and i got a comunication with the printer problem.

It looks like the problem now is solved from the updated kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got mine working by getting the IPv4 from the printer's network settings and adding a printer manually with the URI `socket://<printer.ip.here>`.