# Ubuntu 20.04 HP 4520 printer recognized by hp-setup tool, but tool hangs on step 3

Tags: 20.04, printing, hp

I upgraded to 20.04, and cannot print to my HP 4520.

I have used the hp-setup tool, and the printer has been found on the LAN, but the setup tool hangs on step 3.

I have looked for detailed instructions, but have not found them so far.

Is there a troubleshooting flowchart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an ENVY 4520; HPLIP is superfluous. Get a URI with `driverless` and substitute in `lpadmin -p envy4520 -v URI -E -m everywhere`to set up a print queue. See [here](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting)

Comment: I haven't mastered comment markdown. Aopologies.

Comment: `$ driverless`  ####

Comment: `ipp://HP%20ENVY%204520%20series%20%5B07822E%5D._ipp._tcp.local/`

Comment: `$ lpadmin -p envy4520 -v ipp://HP%20ENVY%204520%20series%20%5B07822E%5D._ipp._tcp.local/ -E -m everywhere`

Comment: `lpadmin: Unable to connect to "HPC8D3FF07822E.local:631": Name or service not known`

Comment: But if I look around
`$ ippfind`
`ipp://HPC8D3FF07822E.local:631/ipp/print`

Comment: BTW, I am able to print from my laptop to the same printer, via wirelsss, also on Ubuntu 20.04.  What settings could I compare?

Comment: "Name or service not known" is a failure to lookup the IP address. This is a network issue, not a printing issue. You could try `ipp://IP_ADDRESS/ipp/print` for the URI.

Comment: Yeah I similarly got `lpadmin: Unable to connect to "HP98E7F4976B22.local:631": Name or service not known`. So then I used `lpadmin -p envy4520 -v ipp://IP_ADDRESS_HERE/ipp/print -E -m everywhere`, replacing "IP_ADDRESS_HERE" with the IP address I found on the printer's on-screen menu. And now printing wirelessly from Ubuntu 20.04 works. Thanks!!