# HP Envy 4520 Printer can't print certain colors...perhaps a driver issue?

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04, printing, hp

I am a newbie at both Ubuntu and troubleshooting printers.
I am using a HP Envy 4520 Printer hooked up through usb to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I looked but wasn't able to figure out the answer using: [Can't find Ubuntu drivers for the HP Envy 4520 printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760925/cant-find-ubuntu-drivers-for-the-hp-envy-4520-printer)

First, the red ink ran out.  After continuing to milk out that cartridge, I eventually replaced with a new color ink cartridge.  However, then the cartridge only printed with colors EXCEPT Red.   I could never get it to print red again.

Later, Black/Greyscale printouts are completely blank.
So now, my printer only prints in blue and yellow.

I thought it was an issue with the cartridge so tried everything here including using hot water to try to dissolve any clot.  https://www.minitool.com/news/hp-envy-4520-not-printing.html

I did the usual restart, clean cartridges, reset to defaults, etc.
So I believe that this bizarre behavior is due to a driver issue but have issues trying to fix this because I am more a windows user and just starting to use ubuntu.

Please advise.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess I should not have posted this during the holidays. I am still struggling with this. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: I have still not got this issue fixed and I doubt that I am the only one.